# Animating NSView property of custom structure type

Tags: objective-c, nsview, nsanimation

I have an `NSView` subclass with a property declared like this in the header:

```
@property (nonatomic) BaseRange range;
```

`BaseRange` is defined as:

```
typedef struct BaseRange {          
    float start;
    float len;
} BaseRange;
```

I want to animate the `range` property using the `NSAnimatablePropertyContainer` protocol.

My class overrides `+ defaultAnimationForKey:` as required.

The problem is that when I call `[myView.animator setRange:<some value>]` (`myView` being a instance of the class in question), `myView` is sent `-setNilValueForKey:` for the `range` key at every step of the animation, except for the final value. IOW, the animation doesn't work.

If I define the `range` property like so:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSSize range;
```

and don't change anything else, no `-setNilValueForKey:` message is sent, but rather intermediate values for the `range` key, as normal.

But I don't want to use `NSSize`, because the `range` key should represent a range rather than a a size.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you return `CAPropertyAnimation` or its subclass from the [`+[NSAnimatablePropertyContainer defaultAnimationForKey:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsanimatablepropertycontainer/1535202-defaultanimationforkey?changes=_8&language=objc) method, the behaviour is expect, as [it works with strict set of values](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Animation_Types_Timing/Articles/PropertyAnimations.html):

> - integers and doubles
> - `CGRect`, `CGPoint`, `CGSize`, and `CGAffineTransform` structures
> - `CATransform3D` data structures
> - `CGColor` and `CGImage` references

To my knowledge `CAAnimation` and its subclasses cannot work with arbitrary values beyond this set and focused primarily to work with Core Graphics properties (layers, frames, colors, etc..). On macOS, however, you can use [`NSAnimation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsanimation?language=objc) class instead, which is much more flexible but requires additional customisation to your class. First you should subclass `NSAnimation` itself and override the [`-[NSAnimation setCurrentProgress:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsanimation/1530843-currentprogress?language=objc) method (this is not mandatory, but otherwise you won't be able to get smooth enough transition between animation steps):

```objc
- (void)setCurrentProgress:(NSAnimationProgress)currentProgress {
    [super setCurrentProgress:currentProgress];

    // Range owner refers to the object (view) with the property of custom struct type
    // Range Key Path helps to locate the property inside the object
    if (!_rangeOwner || !_rangeKeyPath) {
        return;
    }

    static const char *const kTDWRangeEncoding = @encode(TDWRange);

    // Wraps new range with NSValue
    NSValue *newRange = [NSValue value:&(TDWRange){
        .location = (_targetRange.location - _originalRange.location) * currentProgress + _originalRange.location,
        .length = (_targetRange.length - _originalRange.length) * currentProgress + _originalRange.length
    } withObjCType:kTDWRangeEncoding];

    // Sends new value to the object that owns the range property
    [_rangeOwner setValue:newRange
               forKeyPath:_rangeKeyPath];
}
```

In this implementation:

- `TDWRange` refers to the custom structure which represents the range;
- `_rangeOwner` refers to the object which has a property of type `TDWRange`;
- `_rangeKeyPath` refers to the key path by which the `NSAnimation` subclass can find the property;
- `_targetRange` is the value towards which the animation interpolates;
- `_originalRange` is the value of the property before animation gets started.

Then, in your custom view class you should provide a separate means to update a property with the given animation. Provided the animation class is called `TDWRangeAnimation` and the range property is reachable through `@"range"` key path, such a method may look like this:

```objc
- (void)setRange:(TDWRange)range animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if (animated) {
        TDWRangeAnimation *rangeAnimation = [[TDWRangeAnimation alloc] initWithRangeOwnder:self
                                                                              rangeKeyPath:@"range"
                                                                               targetRange:range
                                                                                  duration:0.4
                                                                            animationCurve:NSAnimationEaseOut];
        rangeAnimation.animationBlockingMode = NSAnimationNonblocking;
        [rangeAnimation startAnimation];
    } else {
        self.range = range;
    }
}
```

You are not required to retain the animation object, since it's maintained by the run loop until the animation finishes.

---

P.S. Feel free to refer to [the gist](https://gist.github.com/TheDreamsWind/e1935dff79d4caf19bc33e96c0c02b04) in case you need a complete implementation sample.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I actually was using NSAnimation and thought about using something simpler.